# Modal keeps disappearing after opening

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Modal keeps disappearing when opening when I use a `button` tag to link it with the modal, but if I use an `anchor` tag the problem seems to go away. I have a table with users that when I click on that specific user from drop down I would want to view the info associated with that record in the form of a modal.The modal seems to open but disappears or closes immediately under a `button` tag but not under an `anchor` tag.

The reason I am trying to use a button to open a modal is because I want to check if the "edit" icon is clicked so I can populate the modal with that specific user info. IF someone knows a better way of going about this then please help me.

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
         mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT * from user where id = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_POST['update']);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
            exit(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $password, $name, $dob, $phone, $gender, $age);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    }

.....
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "$dob ($age)"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $phone; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $gender; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-link text-dark dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split m-0 p-0 arrow-none" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class='dripicons-dots-3'></i></button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dashboard-dropdown dropdown-menu-start mt-2 py-1">
                            <button class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center btn btn-sm d-inline-flex align-items-center btn-rounded" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-form" name="update" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><i class='mdi mdi-account-edit me-1'></i>Edit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm d-inline-flex align-items-center btn-rounded" type="submit" name="delete" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><i class='mdi mdi-delete'></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </form>
                <?php  } ?>


... Modal
      <div class="modal fade" id="modal-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-form" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content rounded ">
                            <div class="modal-body p-0">
                                <div class="card p-4">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white ms-auto" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="topModalLabel">Course Info</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <!-- Form -->
                                        <form class="ps-3 pe-3" action="" method="POST">
                                            <div class="mb-3 text-center">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name='update'>Submit</button>
                                            </div>

                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: use anchor link not button, button doesnt support arial props.

Comment: i think your code should be change  like this . your problem will be solved:

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-form" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
  <i class='mdi mdi-account-edit me-1'></i>Edit
</button>

and your modal first line to this:
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">